# Nativescript Android: frame.navigate not working after taking a photo

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm having a weird problem with Nativescript on Android.

I'm using `@nativescript/camera` to take a picture. Once it's saved, user clicks a button and I try to navigate to another page - which isn't working.

Taking the picture and saving it works.
Navigating *without* taking a picture works.

I found out that on Android the app goes into background mode when I activate the camera and comes back to front after the image is saved (interesting to know since that's not the case on iOS), but all the vars and constants are still there and the `page.frame` also.

The app doesn't crash and doesn't throw an error - it simply doesn't navigate.

Any ideas?

(Nativescript 8, plain javascript)

Comment: I tried to use @nstudio/nativescript-cameraplus in the meantime. Doesn't work on Android at all (no preview) and crashes on iOS with the built in buttons…

Comment: Got CameraPlus working on both devices. Still would like to know what the problem with the navigation on the core-camera is.